# Join strings from for loop into a single line

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, nltk

I have a grammar tag producing nltk block which is,

```
    sent_text = nltk.sent_tokenize(text) # this gives us a list of sentences
    # now loop over each sentence and tokenize it separately
    for sentence in sent_text:
          tokenized_text = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
          tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized_text) 
          for word, tag in tagged:
               print(tag)
```

This gives me the following output,

```
    DT
    JJ
    NN
    NN
    VBD
    IN
    DT
    JJ
    NN
```

However, I want the output to single lined like

```
    DT JJ NN NN VBD IN DT JJ NN
```

How do I do this?

Comment: The python3 `print` function has an `end` parameter, set it to `' '`, e.g. `print(tag, end=' ')`: see https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=print%20function#print

Comment: Please do this.. add a comma..  `print tag,`

Comment: @AChampion there is no use copying my answer in the comments

Answer (score 2):

If you want not just print, but store the result in a string, you can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a single [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
tags = [tag 
        for sentence in sent_text 
        for _, tag in nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))]
result = " ".join(tags)
print(result)
```

Note that the `_` is a common variable name for throwaway variables.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
print (tag, end=" ")
```

That should leave a space and not go to next line.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 so does not work. Gives syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

I dont think ultimately you want to print the whole string and keep using `print(tag, end = ' ')` so assign it to new variable is explained below. 
Initialize a variable tag_str on top and use it after print statement like this.

```
tag_str += ' '

tag_str += tag
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using Python 3, you could write directly to `sys.stdout`, which would enable you to skip the newline character.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 2.x
use `print(tag,)`, the `,` puts output in the same line. so you can use `print (tag + ' ',)`

If you are using python 3
use `print(tag, end="")` or `print(tag, end=" ")` depending on whether you want whitespace or not.